# using flex data services in a pyamf client

Tags: python, apache-flex, amf

EDIT NOTE:
I gave this quiestion another look, and decided it's not asked so well. Lets try this one:
I'm trying to emulate this request, and recorded by charls, using pyamf:

AMF Message Message 
Header
Body
[0] Body Part
Target  String  null
Response    String  /2
Content Array
[0] Object  flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage
source  Null
operation   String  someActionOnTheServer
messageId   String  89995D65-FF39-F88B-EACE-5E8B16F2A519
body    Array
clientId    Null
timestamp   Integer 0
timeToLive  Integer 0
destination String  bssefreporting
headers Object

How can I do that using pyamf?

Thanks in advance